# Initial connection to WI-FI

Tags: ethernet, ip, wireless, dhcp

My question is what is happening during the initial connection to a wireless network  , is there an Ethernet connection first and then DHCP or something else is happening before the device receive an IP address . 
I`m asking this because when i run iwlist command in linux there is : ADDRESS : XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic flow starts with 802.11 packet exchange to determine data rates and other capabilites.  After this exchange completes, any WPA/WPA2 or 802.11x authentication happens afterwards before traffic is accepted.

Here is a good explanation from Meraki

[802.11 Association Process](https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/WiFi_Basics_and_Best_Practices/802.11_Association_process_explained)

Once the client is associated completely, then it will send out a DHCP broadcast to get an IP address, DNS etc.

Comment: The link gave  good explanation , and answered my question  , thank you  .